# Does Hibernate JPA 2.1 support Java version 1.6?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-6

My project supports only Java 1.6 and I have to use Hibernate JPA. Since hibernate-jpa-2.1-api provides annotation based support to call stored procedure, I like to use it but afraid if it supports java 1.6 or not.

I tried to search on the net but couldn't find the answer. can someone please help me to know if hibernate-jpa-2.1-api supports Java 1.6 or not?

Comment: Why you don't want to upgrade to new version of Java, at least Java 8

Comment: @YCF_L, My project is using legacy parent pom which contain JPA 2.0 which supports Java 1.6 so I cannot deviate from Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the provider instead of jpa so hibernate doc:

http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.1/

http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/

5.1 -> 5.2 is the exact point where they changed the required java version

Both are compatible with jpa 2.1 though so you should be fine with 5.1